# ng e2e vs protractor command

Tags: selenium, protractor, angular6

What is the difference between doing `ng e2e` and doing `protractor protractor-conf.js`? For me `ng e2e` throws errors (`getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com`) while the second method runs smoothly. Why is there a difference and how can I fix the error?
Note: I am using `directConnect:true`